# How to tell Spark to skip partitions based on a range

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Say I had 100 files stored in S3 belonging to one table that I want to query with Spark SQL. Let's say the table has a `timestamp` column and some other columns. The timestamps are monotonically increasing, so the timestamps in each partition are ordered and less than all timestamps in all subsequent partitions.

I now want to make a query over these files where I have a predicate `timestamp between t1 and t2` or `timestamp > t1` where `t1` might be a timestamp in the middle of these 100 partitions. From what I understand, Spark currently cannot figure out that the timestamps are ordered throughout my partitions and will have to inspect each and every single row in all 100 partitions and look at its timestamp.

My question is: How can I teach Spark to be more intelligent and skip entire partitions? For example, if `t1` is in the middle of these 100 partitions, how can I teach Spark to skip the first 50 partitions?

I know about partition discovery https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery but from what I can tell this only works for "categorical" partitions like `gender=male` and not for ranges. What's my best option here?

Comment: What is the format of your data? Is it Delta Lake, parquet files, csv?

Comment: The format of our data is parquet

Answer (score 0):

I had mostly same situation, data is located in folder like `/root/tenant=tenantId/date=2021-01-01`, I use spark expression like (on python)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date as fdate

events_df = spark.read.parquet('/root') \
        .filter(events_df.tenant_id == tenant_id) \
        .filter((from_date <= fdate(events_df.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
                & (fdate(events_df.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') <= to_date)) \
        .filter(col('item_name').isin(['val1', 'val2', 'val3'])) \
        .select(col('date').alias('file_date'),
                'device_id',
                'dataset_context_id',
                col('free').cast('float').alias('free'),
                'item_time')
```

And I've got the following execution plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [date#13 AS file_date#54, device_id#0, dataset_context_id#1, cast(free#9 as float) AS free#55, item_time#6]
+- *(1) Filter item_name#7 IN (val1,val2,val3)
   +- FileScan parquet [device_id#0,dataset_context_id#1,item_time#6,item_name#7,item_data#9,tenant_id#12,date#13] Batched: false, DataFilters: [item_name#7 IN (val1,val2,val3)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[<path/to/root/>], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(tenant_id#12), (tenant_id#12 = <tenantId>), (cast(cast(gettimestamp(date#13, yyyy-..., PushedFilters: [In(item_name, [val1,val2,val3])], ReadSchema: struct<device_id:string,dataset_context_id:string,item_time:timestamp,item_name:string,item_data:...
```

As you see, there is `PartitionFilters` in the plan, which prooves that spark runs partition filtering on date range. (Spark 3.1.1)